# Update navbar once successful login

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am building a website in react and I will like to update the menu from the navigation bar on successful.

For now, the Navbar is handle in the `header.js` file.

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import SiteLogo from '../assets/images/village-logo.svg';
import './Header.css';
import LoginRegisterModal from './modal/LoginRegisterModal';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import ProfilePicAvater from '../assets/images/avatar.png';
import { Form, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap'
import SearchIcon from '../assets/images/search-icon.svg';

class Header extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {showLogin: false};
    }
      
    openLogin = () => {
        this.setState({showLogin: !this.state.showLogin});
    }

    render() {
        const isLoggedIn = false;
        let loginOrProfile;

        const menuLoginRegister = <Nav.Link 
            ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} 
            href="#" 
            onClick={this.openLogin}
            bsPrefix="header-menu-item"
            >{TextContents.MenuLoginRegister}</Nav.Link>;

        const profileImage = <div>
                <img className="header-avatar-pic" 
                    src={ProfilePicAvater} 
                    alt="user pic"
                />
            </div>
        const menuProfile = 
            <NavDropdown title={profileImage} id="basic-nav-dropdown" bsPrefix="header-drop-down-menu">
                <p bsPrefix="header-drop-down-name">Sebastien Cayet</p>
                <NavDropdown.Divider className="header-divider"/>
                <NavDropdown.Item bsPrefix="header-drop-down-item" href="/profile">{TextContents.MenuProfile}</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item bsPrefix="header-drop-down-item" href="/messages">{TextContents.MenuMessages}</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item bsPrefix="header-drop-down-item" href="/settings">{TextContents.MenuSettings}</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item bsPrefix="header-drop-down-item" href="/logout">{TextContents.MenuLogout}</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>;

        if(isLoggedIn){
            loginOrProfile = menuProfile;
        } else
        {
            loginOrProfile = menuLoginRegister;
        }
        return (
            <div>
            <Navbar className="header-village" width="100" expand="lg">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">
                    <img
                        src= { SiteLogo }
                        width="214"
                        height="28"
                        className="d-inline-block align-top"
                        alt="Village"
                    />
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <InputGroup className="header-search-container">
                    <InputGroup.Prepend>
                        <InputGroup.Text bsPrefix="header-search-prepend" id="inputGroupPrepend">
                        <img
                            src= { SearchIcon }
                            width="17"
                            height="17"
                            className="header-search-img"
                            alt="Village"
                        />
                        </InputGroup.Text>
                    </InputGroup.Prepend>
                    <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        placeholder={TextContents.SearchPlaceHolder}
                        aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend"
                        bsPrefix="header-search-form"
                    />
                    </InputGroup>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav bsPrefix="menu-inline">
                    <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/discover">{TextContents.MenuDiscover}</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/create">{TextContents.MenuCreate}</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link bsPrefix="header-menu-item" href="/howitworks">{TextContents.MenuHiW}</Nav.Link>
                    {loginOrProfile}
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Navbar>
            <LoginRegisterModal show={this.state.showLogin} 
              onHide={() => this.setState({ showLogin: false })}/>
            </div>
            );
        }
}

export default Header;
```

In this file, to allow the test of the profile vs login, I have added a boolean called `isLoggedIn` to switch between the login option and profile drop down list. it's not automatic, I change it myself for texting purpose as the login was completed yet.

I am trying to have this boolean replaced by the login response. in case, of successful login, I switch to `menuProfile`, if not I stay on `menuLoginRegister` and display an error message.

The login is build as below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import './Login.css';
import Config from '../../assets/config/Config';
import axios from 'axios';
import { replace } from "formik";

class LoginRegisterModal extends React.Component {  

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          show: false, 
          rightActive: false,
          email: '',
          password: '',
          userNiceName: '',
          loggedIn: false,
          loading: false,
          error: ''
        };
    }

    open = () => {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }
    
    close = () => {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
   //   this.signup.current.addEventListener('click', () => {
   //     this.container.current.classList.add('right-panel-active');
   //   });  

   //  this.signin.current.addEventListener('click', () => {
   //     this.container.current.classList.remove('right-panel-active');
   //   });  
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        const { show } = this.props;
        if (prevProps.show !== show) {
          if (show) {
            this.open(); // open if parent says to
          } else {
            this.close(); // close if parent says to
          }
        }
    }

    requestSignIn = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.setState({loading: true})

      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username: `${this.state.email}`, password: `${this.state.password}` })
    };
    fetch('http://xx.xx.xx.xx/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', requestOptions)
        .then(async response => {
            const data = await response.json();

            // check for error response
            if (!response.ok) {
                // get error message from body or default to response status
                const error = (data && data.message) || response.status;
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
            console.error('data', data)
            window.open("/myfeed", "_self") //to open new page
            this.setState({loading: false })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.toString() });
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        });
    }

    handleOnChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    }

    createAccount = () => {
      this.close()
    }

    requestForgotPassword = () => {
      this.close()
    }
      
    render() { 

      const styleModal = {
        marginTop: "15%",
        marginLeft: "30%",
        padding: 0,
        width:770,
        height:480,
        backgroundColor:"#ffffffff",
        borderRadius:21.5,
      } //style={styleModal}

      const styleHeaderWhite = {
        fontFamily: "Fredoka One",
        fontSize: "36px", 
        fontWeight: "normal",
        lineHeight: 1,
        color: "#ffffff"  
      }

      const styleHeaderBlack= {
        fontFamily: "Fredoka One",
        fontSize: "36px", 
        fontWeight: "normal",
        lineHeight: 1,
        color: "#333333"  
      }

      const styleTxtWhite = {
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
        fontSize: "14px", 
        fontWeight: "normal",
        lineHeight: 1,
        color: "#ffffff"  
      }

      const styleTxtBlack= {
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
        fontSize: "14px", 
        fontWeight: "normal",
        lineHeight: 1,
        color: "#616161"  
      }

      const whiteBtnStyle = {
        borderRadius: 21, 
        fontSize: "18px" ,
        fontWeight: "bold",
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#ff7255",
        boxShadow: "0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14)",
        paddingTop: "5px",
        paddingBottom: "7px",
        paddingLeft: "20px",
        paddingRight: "20px",
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff", 
        borderColor: "#ffffff",
        fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
    }

    const formStyle = {
      width: "280px",
      height: "40px",
      marginTop:"10px",
      borderRadius: 20,
      backgroundColor: "#f4f7f8",
      fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro",
      textAlign: "left",
    }

    const { email, password } = this.state;
        
    const loginModal = <div className={`containerLogin ${this.state.rightActive ? "right-panel-active" : ""}`}>
                  <div class="form-login-container sign-up-container"> 
                    <form action="#">
                      <h1 style={styleHeaderBlack}>Sign up.</h1>
                      <div class="social-container">
                      <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                      <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                      </div>
                      <span style={styleTxtBlack}>or use your email for registration</span>
                      <input style={formStyle} type="text" placeholder="Name" />
                      <input style={formStyle} type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                      <input style={formStyle} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                      <button style={whiteBtnStyle} onClick={this.createAccount}>Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-login-container sign-in-container">
                  <form onSubmit={this.requestSignIn}>
                    <h1 style={styleHeaderBlack}>Sign in.</h1>
                    <div class="social-container">
                        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <span style={styleTxtBlack}>or use your account</span>
                      <input style={formStyle} 
                        type="text" 
                        placeholder="Email" 
                        name="email"
                        value={ email }
                        onChange={ this.handleOnChange } />
                    <input style={formStyle} 
                        type="password" 
                        placeholder="Password"
                        name="password"
                        value={ password }
                        onChange={ this.handleOnChange }/>
                    <a style={styleTxtBlack} href="#" onClick={this.requestForgotPassword} >Forgot your password?</a>
                    <button style={whiteBtnStyle} type="submit" >Sign In</button>
                  </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="overlay-container">
                    <div class="overlay">
                      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
                          <h1 style={styleHeaderWhite}>Sign in.</h1>
                          <p style={styleTxtWhite}>
                            Nice to see you again.Login and continue the journey.
                          </p>
                          <button style={whiteBtnStyle} class="ghost" onClick={() => this.setState({rightActive: true})}>Sign In</button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
                          <h1 style={styleHeaderWhite}>Hey, new friend!</h1>
                          <p style={styleTxtWhite}>New to the Village? Sign up and start your journey</p>
                          <button style={whiteBtnStyle} class="ghost" onClick={() => this.setState({rightActive: false})}>Sign Up</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>;

      return (       
        <Modal className="modal" show={this.state.show}  size="lg" > 
            {loginModal}
        </Modal>
        );  
    }  
}  
  
export default LoginRegisterModal;
```

For now, I am redirecting to another page on success loggin, I will still do it but im addition I would like to be able to update the header.

The open of the login modal is done through :

```
const menuLoginRegister = <Nav.Link 
            ref="LoginRegisterModal" eventKey={1} 
            href="#" 
            onClick={this.openLogin}
            bsPrefix="header-menu-item"
            >{TextContents.MenuLoginRegister}</Nav.Link>;
```

from the `header.js`

This question may seems probably easy but I am new to React and JavaScript, So I still not really sure.

Is it better to just return the status `true` or `false` or I can just use a Callback and save the login status in Redux for later purpose ?

Any thoughts? Idea on how to do it ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your don't seem to make use of the advantages of Single Page Apps because you are using `window.open` for redirection after a successful login was performed. Therefore, your redux state won't be persistent between page changes. The easiest option would be to store the JSON Web Token in a cookie or inside localStorage and then check for its existence in your `Header` component, for example:

```js
const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('jwt') !== null;
```

Another option would be to use `react-router` or sth. similar for navigation such that your App's state is persisten, and then store the JWT in your redux store and access it in your `Header` component.

**Edit: Some information in Single Page Apps (SPAs)**

The core idea of SPAs is to make a website behave more like a native app which only loads once and doesn't reload while the user is using it, not even when navigating between pages within that website. This is achieved by dynamically replacing parts of the website without reloading an entire new page, which is easily done with React.

The advantage of this is that you can keep the website`s state persistent between page changes, and have faster transitions between different pages.

`react-router` is a library that tells react which parts of the current content of the website should be replaced with what new content given a specific path. To change the current path you have two options:

**1.** Use the HTML `<a>` tag for links and methods of the web API such as `window.open` or `window.location.replace`: **You don't wan't to do this** in an SPA because it tells the browser to load and entire new page.

**2.** Use the link components provided by `react-router`:
Instead of using `<a>` elements for links use the `Link` or `NavLink` components. For programmatic redirects use the `history` package in conjunction with `react-router`.

You can find any information and examples you need in [the official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start).

Comment: please do not hesitate to give more infornation on Single Page Apps. ti's myfirst web site so I can use wrong principle.

Comment: I am using react-router. in the App.js I have define stuff like: <Router>
            <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={ Home } />

Comment: Maybe the use of window.open is the worst things to do.. and i can use the `Router` instead. If yes, I would love some examples

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if things are still unclear to you.